# StackoverflowException when filling array

Tags: c#

I usually spend my time reading and trying to answer the Excel VBA questions but I am trying to learn C# now. Can someone help me understand why I get a `StackOverflowException` error on the second to last line in my code?
I am trying to fill an array via a method.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = GenerateNumbers();
            Console.WriteLine(numbers);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static int[] GenerateNumbers()
        {
            int[] num = new int[10] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
            return GenerateNumbers();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `return GenerateNumbers();` does? This is important to know to correct your misunderstanding.

Comment: Hint: infinite recursion

Comment: use `return num;`  or just `numbers = Enumerable.Range(1,10);`

Comment: I see now. It makes sense. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are confusing the weird VBA way of returning functions with C#. You are returning an infinite recursion, which can be easily fixed by using this:

```
    static int[] GenerateNumbers()
    {
        int[] num = new int[10] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        return num; //you don't return the function name but a variable
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

> A stack overflow is an undesirable condition in which a particular
>   computer program tries to use more memory space than the call stack
>   has available. In programming, the call stack is a buffer that stores
>   requests that need to be handled. http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/stack-overflow

```
 static int[] GenerateNumbers()
 {
     int[] num = new int[10] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
     return GenerateNumbers(); //Here is where the problem happens
 }
```

The problem lies with the return part. You are calling the same function in the same function creating a stack of the same function again and again and... You get the picture.

Change it to

```
return num;
```

Comment: @Mafii Thank you for the heads up. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

By calling `return GenerateNumbers()` at the end of your function, you are running that function over and over again infinitely because there is no way to break the recursion, causing the stack overflow. You should instead use `return num`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're esentially doing:

```
void Main() 
{
    FlipPage();
}

void FlipPage()
{
    FlipPage();
}
```

So like that blond you keep flipping that page in all eternity